# Trouble to run automate test on opera-chromium-driver 2.45 (Opera 60) on Windows 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, windows-10, opera

I have a problem to run automate test on Opera 60 with opera-chromium-driver 2.45 on Windows 10. I have use selenium-standalone-server-3.4.0. On MacOs Mojave this combination of driver and selenium works great, but on Windows 10 Opera started runing, but throws strange error (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist).

I tried to add/remove OperaOptions like "--headless","--no-sandbox" etc. like on other posts on stackoverflow, but none of these will help. Same code with Opera 56 and opera-chromium-driver 2.40 works on Windows, but new driver throws this weird exception.

This is sample of my code

```java
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
//Opera60
OperaOptions oo = new OperaOptions();
oo.addArguments("--headless");
oo.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
oo.addArguments("--no-first-run");
//I have generate link in system to get always "latest" opera
oo.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\latest\\opera.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Users\\root.DESKTOP-KFASMSK\\controller_code\\controller_dependencies\\stuff\\drivers\\WINDOWS\\operadriver.exe");
dc.setCapability(OperaOptions.CAPABILITY, oo);
dc.setBrowserName("operablink");
this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(operation.getSeleniumAddress()), dc);
```

This is a fragment of exception on Selenium

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Opera failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:/Program Files/Opera/latest/opera.exe is no longer running, so OperaDriver is assuming that Opera has crashed.)
  (Driver info: OperaDriver=2.45.3255 (O60),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 868 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KFASMSK', ip: '10.0.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add one more argument `oo.addArguments("--allow-elevated-browser");`.